# standalone spring batch jobs visible on the spring batch admin?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I would like to separate my jobs from the spring batch admin but to still be able to see the jobs in the admin page.

I would like 1 webapp to contain only the admin console and other webapps to contain a job. All the webapps will be deployed on the same weblogic server.

How can I make the jobs visible in the admin console even if the jobs are not in the same war file as the admin console ?

This is the only information I found on the documentation :

> To add job executions from another process just execute a job (e.g.
>   from command line) against the same database that is used by Spring
>   Batch Admin. The UI picks up the meta data from the usual Spring Batch
>   tables.

Comment: 1.  Visible or also able to be launched?
2.  What is the timing for this project?  Spring Cloud Data Flow may be a better option for you...

Comment: visible and able to be launched.

Comment: We have no timing defined yet. we are trying to find the best architecture. We don't want to deploy the admin console each time we want to add a new batch.

Comment: Then definitely take a look at Spring XD/Spring Cloud Data Flow.  Spring Cloud Data Flow is essentially Spring XD v2.0 and will be GA in a few months.  While we're working on the batch features of Spring Cloud Data Flow, Spring XD will give you an idea of what to expect.  You can read more about Spring XD and Spring Cloud Data Flow on our website: http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/ and http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/

Comment: is this the simplest solution ?

Comment: Without writing custom code?  Yes.  It's also the most scalable solution IMHO.  Any specific concerns about those options (this may be better in chat...)